# How to bring wlan0 up without connect to any access point?

Tags: command-line, wireless

How to bring my wlan0 interface up without connect to any access point using command line?

Note: Ubuntu Server 14.04

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer by clicking "Answer Your Question" button. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ifconfig wlan0 up
```

That brings the interface up, but it probably won't even have an IP assigned yet.

Comment: What if 'net-tools' isn't installed on your system?

Answer (score 0):

Remove everything in `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections` folder to remove all network profiles and bring up `wlan0`.

You can do

```
sudo service network manager restart
```

or

```
sudo sytemctl restart NetworkManager
```

On 15.04 and later.

Comment: Sorry Serg. I forgot to tell you about OS version.

Comment: why to remove everything? removing only wifi connections wont work?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the article [Replacing ifconfig with ip](https://www.linux.com/training-tutorials/replacing-ifconfig-ip/) the `ip` method is:

```
ip link set dev wlan0 up
```

if `ip a` list your device as *wlan0*.